# I am getting an error when I am trying to install laravel jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

When I try to install laravel jetstream on my project directory using "composer require laravel/jetstream", it keeps on displaying error message *https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7578: Connection refused), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date*

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/failed-to-connect-to-repopackagistorg-port-443-connection-timed-out?page=1&replyId=694328

Comment: I 've asked them but no one was able to solve the problem that's why I am here

Comment: The error message suggests it's trying to use port 7578. You will need to add that to your firewall rules.

Comment: You need to inform system admin about the blocked ports. It may be due to firewall configuration / Antivirus Software